# How to check if a video was already saved in photos library

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that allows user to save video and images when the user clicks on the download button, but the user can click download 100 times and download the same image or video, and I was wondering is there a way to check if the file have been already save in the library like how WhatsApp does by showing an alert message?

```
func saveVideo(atFilePath:URL) {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: atFilePath)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.displayResponse(message: "video saved successfully"))
            } else {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.displayResponse(message:"fail to save video")
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save Filepath of the video in your local DB(codeData/userdefaults) after successfully save of PHPhotoLibrary, when the user try to download it again, validate local saved file path's first. display alert if you find any existing file path.

Answer (score -1):

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("fileName").path
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
    print("File is already available")
} else {
    print("File is not available")
}
```

You can check the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410277-fileexists

Comment: The OP is asking how to check if a video already exists in Photo Library NOT in the document directory.